# Updating business services in OSB JDeveloper 12c

Tags: wsdl, soa, osb

I have a scenario where the web service that the business service is based on has been updated. I'm looking for the correct approach to updating the business service in the OSB project to reflect the change. Can I download the WSDL and replace the contents of the existing WSDL file and XSD if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following:

- Replace the old WSDL and schemas with the new ones.
- Go to your business service and select the new WSDL
- Validate your project to see if the changes in the WSDL/XSD didn't break any XPaths, XQueries, namespaces,...
- If everything validaties, test your changes